# globals() vs locals() mutability

Tags: python, state, python-internals, mutability

In Python, `globals()` returns a representation of the global symbol table, while `locals()` returns a representation of the local state. While both return a dictionary, changes to `globals()` are effected in the global symbol table, while change to `locals()` have no effect.

Why is this the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it bad idea to modify locals in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997184/why-is-it-bad-idea-to-modify-locals-in-python)

Comment: @BartoszKP: none of the answers there are actually correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The accepted answer says in essence the same what you say - that you shouldn't modify locals because it yields undefined behaviour. If you believe your answer is better perhaps you could consider posting it there, not here. I wouldn't have anything against the other question as a duplicate of this one if you insist. But seems you don't need voting for this :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: There may be *better* dupes out there though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right. This one is the best I've found, but I admit I didn't spend more than 5 minutes on this :)

Comment: "while change to locals() have no effect." If this was the case in 2015, it's not the case anymore. The locals() dictionary is in fact mutable and can be used to set local variables outside of the local scope.

Answer (score 7):

Function locals are highly optimised and determined at compile time, CPython builds on not being able to alter the known locals dynamically at runtime.

You can see this when decoding a function bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     a = 'bar'
...     return a + 'baz'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('baz')
             12 BINARY_ADD          
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [`LOAD_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST) and [`STORE_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST) opcodes use *indices* to load and store variables, because on a frame the locals is implemented as an array. Access to an array is faster than using a hash table (dictionary), such as used for the global namespace.

The `locals()` function, when used in a function, then returns a *reflection* of this array as a dictionary. Altering the `locals()` dictionary won't then reflect that back into the array.

In Python 2, if you use the `exec` statement in your code then the optimisation is (partly) broken; Python uses the slower [`LOAD_NAME` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_NAME) in that case:

```
>>> def bar(code):
...     exec code
...     return a + 'baz'
... 
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (code)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 EXEC_STMT           

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             11 LOAD_CONST               1 ('baz')
             14 BINARY_ADD          
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Also see this [bug report against Python 3](http://bugs.python.org/msg79061) where `exec()` (a function in Py3) doesn't allow you to set local names anymore:

> To modify the locals of a function on the fly is not
>   possible without several consequences: normally, function locals are not
>   stored in a dictionary, but an array, whose indices are determined at
>   compile time from the known locales.  This collides at least with new
>   locals added by exec.  **The old exec statement circumvented this, because
>   the compiler knew that if an exec without globals/locals args occurred
>   in a function, that namespace would be "unoptimized", i.e. not using the
>   locals array.**  Since exec() is now a normal function, the compiler does
>   not know what "exec" may be bound to, and therefore can not treat is
>   specially.

Comment: Why doesn't globals() behave in the same way?

Comment: @lumisota: because globals is a) layered (it also reaches into builtins) and has to support altering at runtime (with the `global` keyword, as well as adding to the module namespace at runtime).