# Delaying evaluation of a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function `my_del` with the following properties:

- it has only one parameter,
- if the parameter passed is a variable with global assignment, it deletes it using `del`,
- otherwise it prints "Variable not assigned",
- no NameError exception should be issued.

---

My first trial:

```
def my_del(var):
    try: 
       del var
    except NameError:
       print("Variable not assigned")
```

This does not work.

*(i)* For an assigned variable:

```
x = 1
my_del(x)
x
# outputs 1
```

the reference did not get deleted. Although not sure, I suppose this is because `var` did not get bound to the global `x`.

*(ii)* For an unassigned variable, an exception is issued:

```
my_del(y)
# NameError exception
```

The function `my_del` did not get the chance to be called, as the exception happens before.

---

My second trial:

```
def my_del(var):
   try: 
       var = var()
       del var
   except NameError:
       print("Variable not assigned")
```

*(i)* For an unassigned variable:

```
my_del(lambda: y)
# prints the string
```

This works fine.

*(ii)* For an assigned variable:

```
x = 1
my_del(lambda: x)
x
# outputs 1
```

we still have `x` referenced. Here `var = var()` creates a local variable, which does not refer to the input parameter.

---

What would be a proper way to create this `my_del` function?

Comment: This function doesn't make any sense. Inside the function, the parameter is a parameter; it's locally bound. You cannot have a `NameError` on a function's parameter, until after you've deleted it. As you're seeing, the `NameError` occurs *outside* the function, when you try to resolve the missing identifier to pass its value to the function. Could you give a bit of context around why you think this is a thing you want at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe *Re: "the parameter is a parameter; it's locally bound".* In, e.g., `def foo(var) var.append(5)`, when defining a list `l` and then calling `foo(l)`, can we say that `var` is globally bound? *Re: "context".* I would not have any specific use of this function. I wanted to see if this idea could be implemented (for fun and to learn the language).

Comment: No we can't say that, you're just passing in a reference to a mutable object. And without a context this isn't a practical and answerable question of use to others.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the additional information about the mutable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're trying to do, but you can get close, by directly manipulating the `globals()` dict. However, modifying `globals()` is generally **not** a good idea. And as as others have said, such a function has no practical use. But anyway...

We can't directly pass the object we want to delete, but we can pass its name.

```
def my_del(name):
    g = globals()
    if name in g:
        del g[name]
    else:
        print(name, 'unknown')

a = 7
print(a)
my_del('a')
try:
    print(a)
except NameError as e:
    print(e)
```

**output**

```
7
name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Very helpful. Happy to learn about `globals()`.

Comment: @unfolx No worries. But please don't directly modify `globals()` like that in normal code. It can be handy to inspect the contents of `globals()` during development, but you really shouldn't change it.

Comment: @unfolx There's also a `locals()` dict, which is equal to `globals()` in the global context of a module (i.e., outside a function or class definition), but inside a function it holds the local vars of the function. However, modifications to `locals()` may not actually change those local variables. See [Why is it bad idea to modify locals in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997184/why-is-it-bad-idea-to-modify-locals-in-python)

Comment: OK, warning understood. Thanks for `locals` and the link.

Answer (score 1):

You have not completely understood what `del` does. `del` simply decrements a reference counter to an object. An object is not truly deleted until the number of references pointing to it is 0 (at which point it is garbage collected). At the point of the function call, there are (at least) two references - the function argument, and the original variable passed to it. Furthermore, deleting one reference (`var`) does not imply deletion of another (`x`).

To see the number of references currently pointing to an object, you may use:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(x)
```

Furthermore, if the only purpose of `my_del` is to (attempt to) delete an object, call `del` directly...

Comment: So a bit of a tl;dr - the code is decrementing the reference count by one which wouldn't have been incremented if the function hadn't been called with the reference :) (So a fairly good do-nothing function)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for `sys.getrefcount`. The idea of `my_del` is basically a `del` that does not issue a NameError exception if the variable is unassigned. It is not really about how useful it is, it is more about how to implement it.

Comment: @unfolx Assuming you are a little cunning with your code design, such things may not be needed... anyway, I hope this gets you a step in the right direction.

Comment: @JonClements and which would have been decremented anyway at the end of the function!