# How can I select a variable by (string) name?

Tags: python, string, variable-variables

I want to return a pre-determined list from my function, based on the string input.

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    text = ['txt', 'doc']
    audio = ['mp3', 'wav']
    video = ['mp4', 'mkv']
    return # what do I return here?

get_ext('audio')  #should return the list ['mp3', 'wav']
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

---

<sub>For the related problem of trying to use strings to *assign or create* variables, see [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/). This question is about looking them up.</sub>

<sub>For lookup *on an existing object* (rather than in the current local variables), see [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610).</sub>

Comment: @timgeb See also a very similar one I could've used to close but didn't - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string

Comment: Which is not the same as the previous one but was also closed the same way. If an answer in the target addresses this question, I think it's O.K.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that would be a better dupe target I suppose, which has been duped again to the target you initially proposed... can't argue with that. (*Although I still think there's a difference between creating a dynamic number of variables and variable lookup by string*)

Comment: @timgeb Yup, that was why I closed it as a dupe of the parent initially :) But now that I've closed the question once, I cannot close it again. Help?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm hesistant to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string because do we really want to teach people to use `globals`? I would rather let the question stay open, but that could totally be my bias since I made the accepted answer.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, that's the other reason I closed as a dupe of the parent... since I stood by that solution more than the `globals` one.

Comment: @timgeb: that duplicate was correct, I've re-closed it. I've added another post in the mix however. No, in this case `globals()` would not be helpful, but the advice to build a dictionary to hold a namespace *is*.

Comment: The other duplicate was *clearly* a duplicate of the canonical; the goal was to use existing strings to create variable names procedurally. The goal here is to use a *single* string to *select an already existing* variable. The approach is wrong in the same way in both cases, and the same underlying advice applies, but this is clearly a different question and I've reopened it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726 is frighteningly bad for something so popular, but it's much more like this question than the variable-variables canonical. If anything, *it* is a duplicate of *this*.

Comment: Note for future closers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/ is still the appropriate target in cases where OP *has already*, e.g., created multiple related variable names algorithmically rather than using a list and then wants to access them. However, sometimes the generation is done by e.g. a GUI form designer and is out of OP's control. In these cases, try to find something more specific.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In most cases like this, an ordinary dictionary will do the job just fine.

```
>>> get_ext = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
...            'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
...            'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']
... }
>>> 
>>> get_ext['video']
['mp4', 'mkv']
```

If you really want or need a function (for which there can be valid reasons) you have a couple of options. One of the easiest is to assign to the `get` method of the dictionary. You can even re-assign the name `get_ext` if you don't have use for the dictionary behind the curtain.

```
>>> get_ext = get_ext.get
>>> get_ext('video')
['mp4', 'mkv']
```

This function will return `None` per default if you enter an unknown key:

```
>>> x = get_ext('binary')
>>> x is None
True
```

If you want a `KeyError` instead for unknown keys, assign to `get_ext.__getitem__` instead of `get_ext.get`.

If you want a custom default-value one approach is to wrap the dictionary inside a function. This example uses an empty list as the default value.

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    types = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
             'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
             'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']
    }

    return types.get(file_type, [])
```

However, @omri_saadon gave the valid remark that the `types = ...` assignment is performed every function call. Here's what you can do to get around that if this bothers you.

```
class get_ext(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
                      'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
                      'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']
        }

    def __call__(self, file_type):
        return self.types.get(file_type, [])

get_ext = get_ext()
```

You can use `get_ext` like a regular function from here on, because in the end callables are callables. :)

Note that this approach - besides the fact that `self.types` is only created once - has the considerable advantage that you can still easily change the file types your function recognizes.

```
>>> get_ext.types['binary'] = ['bin', 'exe']
>>> get_ext('binary')
['bin', 'exe']
```

Comment: I'd suggest you go even further and *just* use a dictionary, Ludoloco.  Why waste time and typing with a function at all?  A dictionary provides the function you are seeking. (as this answer eloquently demonstrates)

Comment: @TheNate You could make this an answer (I'm surprised none of the answers make this point). wrapping a dictionary in a function seems like an awful lot of work just to use round brackets rather than square brackets.

Comment: @JohnColeman I would say this depends on how the function/dict is used further down the road. E.g., if you intend to do a lot of `map`ping or general passing around of the callable and are not interested in membership tests (i.e. `key in mydict`) then the function feels a bit more natural to me. But other than that, I agree and would personally probably just use a dict. It becomes more interesting when the value retrieval is supposed to be coupled with more computation or side effects. Then you have the choice to subclass `dict` (better: `collections.UserDict`) or write your own callable.

Comment: Another case where not using 'just' a dict is a bit more elegant is when you want the same default return value != `None` for every lookup. (An empty list, as suggested in this answer, for example.)

Comment: @timgeb I don't really disagree, but OP comes across as a new Python programmer who isn't familiar with dictionaries. This might be an XY problem where the solution to their actual problem is just a basic dictionary used in a straightforward way.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree. I have restructured my answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to define a dictionary as in [@timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496454/7434365), then you can call [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), which gives you a `dict` of the variables available in the local scope.

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    text = ['txt', 'doc']
    audio = ['mp3', 'wav']
    video = ['mp4', 'mkv']
    return locals()[file_type]
```

and a test to show it works:

```
>>> get_ext("text")
['txt', 'doc']
```

Comment: Nah, this works but it's a terrible approach to take. It takes advantage of the fact that `locals()` returns a dictionary-- use a real dictionary, that's what they're for!

Comment: @alexis I don't want to say that your comment is not valid, but I can't get behind the reasoning "It takes advantage of the fact that locals() returns a dictionary". When do we ever not "take advantage" of knowing what the return value of a call can do?

Comment: My point is that this solution relies on the same data type that it pretends to avoid. It is a hack that obscures the distinction between variable names and data... and to what benefit? It doesn't even  avoid the data type that _should_ have been used, in a perfectly straightforward way, from the start.

Comment: PS. It's good/interesting to know about `locals()`; it's just a terrible way to approach this task.

Comment: @alexis I agree that `explicit is better than implicit`, but the `dict` created by `locals()` is as "real" as any other. Just keep in mind that [modifying it may not work like you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997184/why-is-it-bad-idea-to-modify-locals-in-python).

Comment: For completeness: `globals()` does the same thing for the global scope.

Comment: I work with a COTS product that allows us to script in Python. Our script will be passed, in a predictably named variable, the name of a variable that holds a value we may want to work with. @timgeb's "accepted" answer doesn't work at all in this case, as I have no control over how the COTS product passes data to my script. On the other hand, this `locals()[var_with_varname]` approach from @KarlKnechtel works great!

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use dict with tuple/list values like so:

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    d = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
         'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
         'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']}
    return d[file_type]


print(get_ext('audio'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary:

```
def get_ext(file_type):
    d = {'text' : ['txt', 'doc'],
         'audio' : ['mp3', 'wav'],
         'video' : ['mp4', 'mkv']}
    try:
        return d[file_type]
    except KeyError:
        return []

get_ext('audio') # ['mp3', 'wav']
```

returns empty list in case that key does not exists.
how ever this is simplest answer that came in my mind , for better answer see @timgeb answer.

Comment: I guess someone grumpy downvoted because of your wrongly indented `return`. Just fix that. +1 because this is the right idea.

Comment: Actually, I don't like this approach as each call to `get_ext` an new dictionary is created which is redundant. It's better to seperate the creation of the dict and the getter.

Comment: wats cache man?

Comment: @omri_saadon well, are you sure?

Comment: @timgeb. What do you mean? Each time you call to `get_ext` there is an new assignment to variable `d`.

Comment: @omri_saadon yes you catched very fair,its not pythonic that way

Comment: @timgeb , Yes, in this case the creation of the dict is pretty simple Although if the creation of the dict is really complicated, the performance would get real bad.

Comment: @omri_saadon your comment is valid. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer by @timgeb I'd use a dictionary, but if you're accessing a lot, care about speed and don't want to define a class you can use caching.

```
from functools import lru_cache

def get_ext(file_type):
    d = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
         'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
         'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']}
    return d[file_type]

@lru_cache(maxsize=3, typed=False)
def get_ext_cached(file_type):
    d = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
         'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
         'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']}
    return d[file_type]

from timeit import timeit

# non cached
print(timeit(stmt='get_ext("text")', globals={'get_ext': get_ext}))
# 0.48447531609922706 on my machine

# cached
print(timeit(stmt='get_ext("text")', globals={'get_ext': get_ext_cached}))
# 0.11434909792297276
```

Though for this particular case it's likely overkill and you can just call get on the dictionary directly (cache just builds its own dictionary and does exactly that) you can use this in future for any pure functions which are effectively a computed lookup.

```
d = {'text': ['txt', 'doc'],
    'audio': ['mp3', 'wav'],
    'video': ['mp4', 'mkv']}

# 0.05016115184298542
print(timeit(stmt="d['text']",
             globals={'d':d,'c':c}))
```

Comment: That is a lot of typing compared to replacing the function with a dictionary that is accessed directly by the caller.