# How to iterate of a list of dataframe's name to get the 1st value of 1st row of every dataframe in the list

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Let's say I have 3 dataframes:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'area':['lab','class_room','pool','gardem'],'%_chance':[0.33,0.27,.30,.10]})
da=pd.DataFrame({'city':['jess','nobytown','paris','miami'],'%_chance':[0.5,0.30,.15,.05]})
db=pd.DataFrame({'country':['china','japan','france','eua'],'%_chance':[0.43,0.27,.20,.10]})
```

and a list with the dataframe's name:

```
dataframe_list_name = ['df','da','db']
```

I want to get the value of the first row of the first column of every dataframe(in this case there's only 3 but I can have more) and append them to a list.

I am trying this:

```
f=[]
for name in dataframe_names:
    x=name.iloc[0,0]
```

This is not working because name is a string.  My question is:  How can I iterate over that dataframe's name list to make thi code works?

The output should be:

f=['lab','jess','china']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select a variable by (string) name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/how-can-i-select-a-variable-by-string-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the names in the list, but rather the variables (i.e., the dataframes) themselves:

```
dataframes = [df,da,db]

f = [d.iat[0,0] for d in dataframes]
```

output: `['lab', 'jess', 'china']`

It is theoretically possible to use the names, **but thus is a bad practice and makes the code poorly explicit** and prone to bugs/errors/unwanted behavior (so don't do it please!):

```
dataframe_list_name = ['df','da','db']
g = globals()

f = [g[name].iat[0,0] for name in dataframe_list_name]
```