# How to convert a sequence of letters into a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

For Example:

| col1 |
| --- |
| 'ACDE' |
| 'ADEC' |

I have:

```
A = 0.89
C = 1.21
D = 1.33
E = 1.47
```

So the column should become

| col1 |
| --- |
| [0.89, 1.21, 1.33, 1.47] |
| ['0.89','1.33','1.47','1.21'] |

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain the context of the problem. I **guess** you are using Pandas, so I added that tag. If so, you should at least explain this much. Ideally, show the starting values for the code as code, rather than as a table (for example, show code that will create that Dataframe). If this is **not** Pandas, then please explain what it is instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should really not try to [access variables by a string representation of their name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/how-can-i-select-a-variable-by-string-name).

Use a dictionary as container:

```
d = {'A': 0.89, 'C': 1.21, 'D': 1.33, 'E': 1.47}

# or
d = {'A': A, 'C': C, 'D': D, 'E': E}
```

Then you can break your string into characters and `map` the values:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extractall('(.)')[0].map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
df['col1'] = [[d.get(c) for c in s] for s in df['col1']]
```

output:

```
                       col1
0  [0.89, 1.21, 1.33, 1.47]
1  [0.89, 1.33, 1.47, 1.21]
```