# How can import a column of data from excel to python as a variable and assign the corresponding heading as the name of the variable?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large excel data with one sheet (.xlsx) such as the following:

| Time | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| ... | ... |

I need to extract every column as a variable to python and I need to use the corresponding heading of the column in excel as the variable name in python (e.g. in Time = [1,2,...]).

So far I get the values as following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

directory = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.realpath("Data.xlsx")
data = pd.read_excel(path)
```

It automatically excludes the headings from the numbers. I can get the headings as objects as follows:

```
datanames = Series (data.columns,dtype='object')
```

which gives:

```
In [42]:datanames
Out[42]: 
0             Time
1             Flow
.
.
.
```

but I'm not able to allocate the headings to each column.

I appreciate your support.
Regards
EMO

Comment: You might check out one of these posts.  This is probably a duplicate at some level: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/how-can-i-select-a-variable-by-string-name

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you are asking how to turn each column in a DataFrame into list and assigning that list to a variable named after the column.  Is that right?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, yes exactly... The data is initially in .xlsx format. Each column has a heading. I need to read each column from the excel file as a list. Moreover I need to name each list the same as its corresponding heading in the excel file. I gave an example above.

Comment: If you're willing to assign to global scope you can do `globals().update(data.to_dict(orient='list'))`. Better would be to leave the data in a dictionary as in `d = data.to_dict(orient='list')`.  Even better would be to do nothing and just use the DataFrame.