# How do you zip lists where the names of the pairs of lists to be zipped comes from a different list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following lists:

```
Factor1 = [1,2,3,4]

Factor2 = [5,6,7,8]

Factor3 = [9,10,11,12]
```

And the combination of the names of the lists:

```
Combination = [['Factor1','Factor2'], ['Factor3','Factor1']]
```

I would like to refer to the list `Combination` to combine the elements of the `Factor*` lists by zipping the list and the result as follows:

```
Combination1 = [(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)]
Combination2 = [(9,1),(10,2),(11,3),(12,4)]
```

Note that I have simplified the problem because my `Combination` list has more than 1000 combinations while the current example has only 2. Hence, I wanted to iterate the process above.

The idea is to code as below:

```
Combination1 = list (zip(Factor1,Factor2))
```

But the problem is I am not sure how do you use the elements of the `Combination` list to as an input to the `zip` portion of the code.

Comment: Is it possible to put your `Factor` lists in a dictionary? Have the key as the list name and the value as the list itself. That way, you can access your list by name. Partially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47496415/2745495

Comment: You can use `globals()['Factor*']` to get the corresponding list, where `*` is the number you want. Not a pretty solution, but it should work.

Comment: Lists don't *have names*. You have some strings. Then you have source code. Don't try to relate those two. If you want some string associated with some list, **make that association in your code**. You could use a `dict`, for example, to map those strings to lists