# Loop over string values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops

I am trying to loop over a line of code with string values from a list:
(I am trying to join the dummy variables I got from pandas. get_dummies to the original dataframe. var1, 2, 3 are dummies)

Wihtout a loop:

```
df.index = var1.index
df = df.join(var1)

df.index = var2.index
df = df.join(var2)

df.index = var3.index
df = df.join(var3)
```

And to reduce the redundant coding, I tried to put these in to a loop:

```
dummmies = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
for item in dummies:
    df.index = item + '.index'
    df = df.join(item)
```

and this is generating the error that says Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind 'var1.index' was passed.

Could you please help me how I resolve this?
I have multiple dummies to join back and I really want to make this loop work.
Thank you!!

Comment: Why with strings?

Comment: [mre]. As it is, your code cannot be reproduced. Please define a sample of df and these variables. See [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Regardless from  inside a loop or not, lines like `df.index = var1.index` will overwrite the index of the original df. What is the point of this? Please make it clear what is your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should achieve what you want if you don't use strings but the actual variables:

```
dummmies = [var1, var2, var3]
for item in dummies:
    df.index = item.index
    df = df.join(item)
```

If you really want that initial list to be strings, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/how-can-i-select-a-variable-by-string-name) with all listed caveats there. For example, if the variables are global, you could do this:

```
dummmies = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
for item_name in dummies:
    item = globals()[item_name]
    df.index = item.index
    df = df.join(item)
```

Comment: Worked!! tysm!!

Answer (score 0):

The 'concat' function may help u in the shortest way:

```
df = pd.concat([df, var1, var2, var3], axis=1)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

# sample
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 15]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# samples
var1 = pd.get_dummies(df['Category'], prefix='var1')
var2 = pd.get_dummies(df['Category'], prefix='var2')
var3 = pd.get_dummies(df['Category'], prefix='var3')

df = pd.concat([df, var1, var2, var3], axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Category  Value  var1_A  var1_B  var1_C  var2_A  var2_B  var2_C  var3_A  var3_B  var3_C
0        A     10    True   False   False    True   False   False    True   False   False
1        B     20   False    True   False   False    True   False   False    True   False
2        C     15   False   False    True   False   False    True   False   False    True
```

Comment: @Oca I removed the picture, and added text instead of it

Comment: Worked!! without a loop and a simpler line of code. Tysm!!

Comment: @serena if u like the solution, if u upvote or accept it, I‘ll be pleased, thanks..